# Many 404 errors for clientsite.com/us/htt

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, apache, http-status-code-404

A client recently launched a site and is seeing thousands of 404'd requests for:
    clientsite.com/us/htt
... where the appended "htt" isn't a valid endpoint.  Here's what I know:

- It's a WordPress-based site
- Most errors come from some form of MS IE browsers, but there are a couple Firefox offenders
- All errors have a referrer within clientsite.com
- We can't seem to recreate the request by viewing traffic in an HTTP proxy and browsing the site, with JavaScript on or off.
- I've egrepped all files for 'htt[^p]', 'slice', and 'substr' and can't find anything glaringly wrong

Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you give us a link to that page? Have you visited itself with IE and traced requests?

Comment: Is there no way to capture the referer when a 404 in encountered in Wordpress? I don't see how this is programming related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into your access_log if using apache and look at the referrer. Best place to start looking.

Comment: A combination of the referring locations and browser user agents helped us track down the bug: A bit of JavaScript that extracts and preload background-images was failing under certain conditions and just returning "htt" as the image url.